# Plural pronoun for singular (collective) noun and instead of him/her?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, pronouns, genderless-pronouns

For example: *The government **is** being flayed for **their** abysmal performance.*

Is this sentence correct? Can we use singular verb "is" and plural "their" simultaneously?

Also, can we use they/them instead of him/her to avoid mentioning specific genders? For example: ***No one*** was allowed to see **their** marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, a collective can be treated as a plural. While in the US, it's generally considered a singular.

But, that aside, the two components of the sentence should be in agreement.

So it would be one or the other of the following:

> The government **are** being flayed for **their** abysmal performance.
>   The government **is** being flayed for **its** abysmal performance.

Which of those two is specifically correct would be a matter of style and regional use.

---

Although *they* and *their* can be used as a gender-neutral singular third-person pronoun, that only applies to people (or creatures or certain things that have been treated in a gendered way). Object and concepts don't have a gender.

In short, when discussing individuals and the pronoun used to describe them, consider the following (discounting gender specificity):

> ✔ No one was allowed to see their marks.
>   ✔ No one was allowed to see one's marks.
>   ✔ No one was allowed to see his marks.
>   ✔ No one was allowed to see her marks.
>
> ✘ No one was allowed to see its marks.

But the reverse is true of objects or concepts that have no gender:

> ✘ No car was allowed to park with their doors open.
>   ✘ No car was allowed to park with one's doors open.
>   ✘ No car was allowed to park with his doors open.
>   ✘ No car was allowed to park with her doors open.
>
> ✔ No car was allowed to park with its doors open.